# WPF: Binding is lost when bindings are updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a WPF-Application for controlling a WCF-RESTful service, i.e. for starting, initializing and stopping it. Therefore I have a `MainWindow` UI which contains a `UserControl` to configure settings. When I initialize my service, some data is loaded into `DependencyProperties` and `ObservableCollections` to display it in the GUI. Here is the part of the method where I update these settings:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    private void InitializeService (bool reInitialize = false) {
        var restService = (RestService)this.ServiceHost.SingletonInstance;
        var settings = restService.GetSettings();
        //UCSettings is the "x:name" of the embedded UserControl "UserControlSettings" in this window
        this.UCSettings.ExecutionTimes.Clear();
        settings.ExecutionTimes.ForEach(x => this.UCSettings.ExecutionTimes.Add(x));
        this.UCSettings.TableConfigurationLoader = settings.Timer.Find(x => x.Name == "TableConfigLoader");
    }
}


public partial class UserControlSettings : UserControl {
    public ObservableCollection<ExecutionTime> ExecutionTimes { get; set; }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TableConfigurationLoaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TableConfigurationLoader", typeof(Setting), typeof(UserControlSettings), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Setting)));
    public Setting TableConfigurationLoader {
        get { return (Setting)this.GetValue(TableConfigurationLoaderProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(TableConfigurationLoaderProperty, value); }
    }
}

public class Setting {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public int ExecutionTimeId { get; set; }
}

public class ExecutionTime {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In the Code-Designer (`UserControlSettings.xaml.cs`) these properties are used in some bindings for a `ComboBox`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="InsightTool.Gui.UserControlSettings" x:Name="UCSettings">
    <ComboBox x:Name="CbConfigLoadingExecutionTime" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UCSettings, Path=ExecutionTimes}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=UCSettings, Path=TableConfigurationLoader.ExecutionTimeId}" SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
</UserControl>
```

When I first load in the data with the `InitializeService` method, everything works fine. The `ComboBox` is filled with the data of the `ObservableCollection` and the matching value is selected automatically by the `ExecutionTimeId`.
When I try to "reinitialize" the service, I call the same method again, but the `SelectedValue` binding does not work anymore. I checked the values of these properties in the debugger, but they are set correctly in this method again. What am I doing wrong here? Some samples:

Correct display first load:
[image: Correct display first load]

Incorrect display seconds load:
[image: incorrect display seconds load]

Comment: Did you replace the ObservableCollection without raising PropertyChanged?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I only clear and refill this collection. Normally it should raise PropertyChange automatically when there a changes, or am I wrong?

Comment: But the ItemsSource binding does work, i.e. the ComboBox has a list of execution times? Does this new list contain the previously selected value, i.e. an ExecutionTime with the same `Id`?

Comment: check your DataContext and Binding at runtime with Snoop

Comment: @Clemens Yes it has for both suggestions of you. If a open the `ComboBox` the items are still there. It looks like that only the auto-selection fails

Comment: @blindmeis Thx for your hint. It just seems that the `SelectedValue` is set correctly but the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` are not set anymore if a update my gui using the method above.

Comment: @blindmeis There is also a red mark for `SelectedValue`, but neither a binding error text, nor is the value field empty.

Comment: @rbr94 where u r setting `ExecutionTimeId` .

Comment: @AnjumSKhan In InitializeService() I set the whole instance / object of `Setting`

Comment: @rbr94 Please set `ExecutionTimeId` explicitly right at the end of InitializeService () and see if this works.

Comment: @rbr94 Close enough; it raises CollectionChanged when items are added/removed, and the control will subscribe to that.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Any idea, why my post below works correctly (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39587798/6489036)? Why is it necessary to create a new instance instead of only overriding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableConfigurationLoader` is a dependency property. That means a lot of things, but one of them is that when you change the value of `TableConfigurationLoader` to a different instance of `Setting`, an event is raised, and this `Binding` handles that event and updates `SelectedValue` on the combo box:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=UCSettings, Path=TableConfigurationLoader.ExecutionTimeId}"
```

However, `Setting.ExecutionTimeId` isn't a dependency property. It's a regular .NET CLR property, which doesn't notify anybody of anything when its value changes. So if you change the `ExecutionTimeId` property of the same old `Setting` that's already in `TableConfigurationLoader`, nobody knows and nothing happens.

Since `Setting` is not a control class, you don't particularly need or want its properties to be dependency properties. Instead, you can treat it as a viewmodel. In implementation terms, all a viewmodel really is, is any class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. With changes to `Setting` shown below, I think the binding should work as you expect, if I correctly understand your problem. I've changed `IsEnabled` so it will raise `PropertyChanged` as well; you may not actually need that, but it's illustrative.

You may need to do the same with your `ExecutionTime` class.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
}

public class Setting : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    #region IsEnabled Property
    private bool _isEnabled = false;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isEnabled)
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion IsEnabled Property

    #region ExecutionTimeId
    private int _executionTimeId = 0;
    public int ExecutionTimeId
    {
        get { return _executionTimeId; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _executionTimeId)
            {
                _executionTimeId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion ExecutionTimeId
}
```

There are three (ish) mechanisms in WPF for notifying things that properties have changed, and you need to be using one or another somehow if you want things to update correctly:

- Dependency properties of dependency objects: For properties of controls
- `INotifyPropertyChanged`: For properties of viewmodels
- `INotifyCollectionChanged`: For collections.

  A collection property should also raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` when you assign a new collection instance to it. A given instance of the collection will handle raising its own events when its contents change.

  `ObservableCollection<T>` and `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>` implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` so you don't have to; it's a big hassle to implement that one properly so you really don't want to go there.

Comment: Thx for your help! I will try it

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new instance of `Setting` before referring to the actual object solved my problem. It seems that the reference to the specific property of `Setting` is lost, if I just "override" the existing instance of this property:

```
var settings = restService.GetSettings();
this.UCSettings.ExecutionTimes.Clear();
settings.ExecutionTimes.ForEach(x => this.UCSettings.ExecutionTimes.Add(x));
this.UCSettings.TableConfigurationLoader = new Setting();
this.UCSettings.TableConfigurationLoader = settings.Timer.Find(x => x.Name == "TableConfigLoader");
```

Comment: Are you saying that the value of `TableConfigurationLoader.ExecutionTimeId` changed, but the UI doesn't recognize that fact unless you set `TableConfigurationLoader` to a different object instance first?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the case

Answer (score 0):

Try adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to the binding like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="InsightTool.Gui.UserControlSettings" x:Name="UCSettings">
<ComboBox x:Name="CbConfigLoadingExecutionTime" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UCSettings, Path=ExecutionTimes}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=UCSettings, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Path=TableConfigurationLoader.ExecutionTimeId}" SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Because `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect on a `SelectedValue` binding. Can't believe that anybody upvoted this.